# How to read inputs from stdin and enforce an encoding?

Tags: python, file, utf-8, io, stdin

The goal is to continuously read from `stdin` and enforce `utf8` in both Python2 and Python3.

I've tried solutions from:

- [Writing bytes to standard output in a way compatible with both, python2 and python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932332/writing-bytes-to-standard-output-in-a-way-compatible-with-both-python2-and-pyth/23932488#23932488)
- [Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding/16549381#16549381)

I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import io
import sys

# Supports Python2 read from stdin and Python3 read from stdin.buffer
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932488/610569
user_input = getattr(sys.stdin, 'buffer', sys.stdin)


# Enforcing utf-8 in Python3
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549381/610569
with io.TextIOWrapper(user_input, encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # Reads the input line by line
        # and do something, for e.g. just print line.
        print(line)
```

The code works in Python3 but in Python2, the TextIOWrapper doesn't have a read function and it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfin.py", line 12, in <module>
    with io.TextIOWrapper(user_input, encoding='utf-8') as fin:
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

---

That's because in Python the `user_input` , i.e. `sys.stdin.buffer` is an 
`_io.BufferedReader` object and its attribute has `readable`:

```
<class '_io.BufferedReader'>

['__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_checkClosed', '_checkReadable', '_checkSeekable', '_checkWritable', '_dealloc_warn', '_finalizing', 'close', 'closed', 'detach', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'peek', 'raw', 'read', 'read1', 'readable', 'readinto', 'readinto1', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'seekable', 'tell', 'truncate', 'writable', 'write', 'writelines']
```

While in Python2 the `user_input` is a file object and its attributes don't have `readable`:

```
<type 'file'>

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a fully-fledged `io.TextIOWrapper`, but just a decoded stream for reading, you can use `codecs.getreader()` to create a decoding wrapper:

```
reader = codecs.getreader('utf8')(user_input)
for line in reader:
    # do whatever you need...
    print(line)
```

`codecs.getreader('utf8')` creates a factory for a `codecs.StreamReader`, which is then instantiated using the original stream.
I'm not sure the `StreamReader` supports the `with` context, but this might not be strictly necessary (there's no need to close STDIN after reading, I guess...).

I've successfully used this solution in situations where the underlying stream only offers a very limited interface.

#### Update (2nd version)

From the comments, it became clear that you actually need an `io.TextIOWrapper` to have proper line buffering etc. in interactive mode; `codecs.StreamReader` only works for piped input and the like.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13189316/1698431), I was able to get interactive input work properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import io
import sys

user_input = getattr(sys.stdin, 'buffer', sys.stdin)

with io.open(user_input.fileno(), encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do whatever you need...
        print(line)
```

This creates an `io.TextIOWrapper` with enforced encoding from the binary STDIN buffer.

Comment: Not really right if the buffer is needed to stream. If you try the code snippet in the OP using Python3, you would see a different behavior. The `sys.stdin` behaves differently from a normal `input()` or `raw_input()`. In my scenario, the stdin is sort of necessary to keep the stream, e.g. if there's a socket and the stream shouldn't be closed.

Comment: For context, this code is to be used in https://github.com/marian-nmt/marian-dev/blob/master/scripts/server/client_example.py where the socket is open for user input from stdin. Although it's possible to write a while loop to use `input()`, it's a little odd to do so when `stdin` inherently does that. The issue is when utf8 string is passed, there's a need to handle it, thus the `io.TextIOWrapper` =)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comments. I didn't think about the built-in `[raw_]input()`, I just reused your `user_input` variable, which is defined in the OP as `getattr(sys.stdin, 'buffer', sys.stdin)`. Unless there is a mistake, the proposed solution should work with streams (it doesn't close STDIN or something).

Comment: Try the script in the OP, it behaves a little differently from yours =)

Comment: @alvas what is this different behaviour you talk about? Can you be more specific? I tried to be more clear about the proposed solution.

Comment: Try using `stdin` interactively as your input instead of piping the input. When using `stdin` it behaves differently. For your script in Python3, `enter` then `ctr+D` needs to be invoked before the script does something. But in the OP with Python, the enter flushes the buffer.

Comment: Try the script in the OP and just run and test, I hope the explanation makes sense.

Comment: @alvas I see now. Yes, with the `codecs.StreamReader`, you need repeated `ctrl+D` signals to trigger flushing. And it took me three of them to end the script...

Comment: I made a new update to the answer. This worked fine in interactive mode when I tested it.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the right syntax to replicate the OP code behavior in Python2 and Python3! Now it's a puzzle why we would need these boilerplates code to buffer streaming, I'll dig into the CPython code =)

Comment: Well, to some extent this boilerplate is the price you pay for Py2/3 compatibility, I guess. I've seen worse, though...

Comment: The lesson I learnt in this is that in most cases you shouldn't try to instantiate `io` classes directly, but instead use `io.open()`.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I wonder, should we pass closefd=False to io.open() to prevent the stdin file descriptor from being closed? (I'm not sure the what would be the consequences of closing a stdio file descriptor on diferent platforms).

Comment: @ejm I guess closing a stdio is not a problem, unless you want to further use it in the same process of course. I generally try to avoid too, though. You can just omit the `with` statement, so the file won't be closed.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried forcing utf-8 encoding in python as follow :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: The point was to avoid setting locale. Thus the script in supporting Python2 and Python3. And also, reloading default encoding is discouraged =(

Comment: This affects implicit conversions between Unicode and ASCII, **globally**. This is a terrible idea, as libraries have been built to rely on non-ASCII data throwing an exception. That expectation is broken with this change.